# multiple condition if statement string keywords: in, not in

Tags: python

I have a list of strings.  I'm trying to remove elements that have certain substrings.  If I use the following, only elements containing 'Cantab' are removed:

```
for line in merged:
    if 'Duke' in line and 'Sir' not in line or 'Cantab' in line or 'Rick' in line:
        merged.remove(line)
```

If I try to break up the conditional, my target results aren't achieved, but I successfully remove elements that contain Duke, but not Sir Duke.:

```
if 'Duke' in line and 'Sir' not in line:
    merged.remove(line)
```

This works as expected:

```
if 'Duke' in line and 'Sir' not in line:
    merged.remove(line)
elif 'Cantab' in line:
    merged.remove(line)
```

But the following only removes elements containing 'Cantab'!!!:

```
if 'Duke' in line and 'Sir' not in line:
    merged.remove(line)
elif 'Cantab' in line:
    merged.remove(line)
elif 'Rick' in line:
    merged.remove(line)
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the logic here.  Thanks!

Comment: You are using a single `if statement` which means that if one of the branches is taken, then the rest won't be considered. Instead, try separating each condition into a separate `if statement`. i.e. replace `elif`s with `if`. See if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, do not iterate over a list *and* remove items from the list at the same time. It shifts the internal index of the items yet-to-be-iterated-over, so that not all items are iterated over.

You can fix the problem by looping over a copy of `merged`:

```
for line in list(merged):
```

---

This example illustrates the problem:

```
merged = ['Cantab', 'Duke', 'Cantab', 'Duke', 'Cantab', 'Duke']
for line in merged:
    print(line)
    if 'Duke' in line and 'Sir' not in line or 'Cantab' in line or 'Rick' in line:
        merged.remove(line)           
print(merged)
```

prints

```
Cantab  # only the Cantab lines are being iterated over!
Cantab
Cantab
['Duke', 'Duke', 'Duke']
```

Consider the first iteration of the loop. When `line` equals `Cantab`, the first `Duke` has internal index of 1. But after `Cantab` is removed, the first `Duke`'s internal index becomes 0. But Python advances the loop index to 1! Now the *second* `Cantab` is at index 1, so the first `Duke` is completely skipped.

---

Alternately, you can fix the problem without making a copy of `merged` by iterating over the list backwards. Done this way, deleting the current item in `merged` is safe because the position of the yet-to-be-iterated-over items is not modified:

```
merged = ['Cantab', 'Duke']*3
for i in range(len(merged)-1, -1, -1):
    line = merged[i]
    if 'Duke' in line and 'Sir' not in line or 'Cantab' in line or 'Rick' in line:
        del merged[i] 
print(merged)
```

prints

```
[]
```

as desired.

Comment: Sneaky! Is there a more obvious way of creating a copy to loop over rather than taking a full slice?

Comment: Alternatively, iterate over the loop *backwards*. Then it is safe to remove the last item.

Comment: Thanks.  A silly mistake that I've made before.  Thanks for the quick solution.

Comment: @TomFenech: `list(merged)` will also return a shallow copy of `merged`. There is also `import copy; copy.deepcopy(x)` for deep copies -- a copy that also copies the items inside the list recursively. (Not needed here, but useful to know about.)

Comment: There's a list of ways to copy a list [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/2088135) but it seems that the `[:]` slice is the fastest. It would be nice if there was something a little more readable but it works, so +1

Comment: @TomFenech: Thanks for the question. I've changed my answer to use `list(merged)` since readability/understandability is more important than premature optimization.